# Autopostback in the same webpage

Tags: asp.net, webforms, checkbox, autopostback

I have a page (let's say page1) that open the page2 using:

```
showModalDialog(page2, '', 'dialogWidth:55em; dialogHeight:50em; status:0');
```

I am facing 2 problem (in this post i am gonna write the first one):

1- i have in page2, several checkboxes that allow autoposback in order to make some changes in the form itself. As i previously mentioned the page2 is opened by the page1 using javascript. So each time i check any of those checkboxes the page open a second form (same as page2 but with the changes)

How can I limit this is the same form?

Answer (score 0):

i am not unkown to showmodalDialog
However in javascript we do like

How do I open a new browser window?

Answer: To open a new browser window, use the window.open() method. For example, the following code opens this page in a new window.

myRef = window.open(''+self.location,'mywin','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');

sName   String specifying the name of the new window. This name can be used in the same constructions as the frame name provided in the frame tag within a frameset . For example, you can use hyperlinks of the form , and the hyperlink destination page will be displayed in your new window.

If a window with this name already exists, then window.open() will display the new content in that existing window, rather than creating a new one.

For more info do google search on "javascript open only single window"